# Untouchable types when specializing an unused type variable

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, type-families

I'm creating an eDSL for my haskell program that would allow defining a set of instructions to store data. These instructions may depend on each other results, and even serialized to file to be further restored. Here is something I came up with (rather verbose, but it's the least code amount I could extract to reproduce my problem):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, RankNTypes, ExistentialQuantification, FlexibleContexts #-}
module Untouchable where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Writer
import System.Random

class ResultClass e where
  type ResultMonad :: * -> *
  statementAResult :: ResultMonad (e Int)
  literalResult    :: a -> ResultMonad (e a)

data Statement result = StatementA | StatementB (result Int)
data StatementWithResult result t = StatementWithResult (Statement result, result t)
data AnyStatementWithResult result = forall t. AnyStatementWithResult (StatementWithResult result     t)
type Program result a = (ResultClass result, ResultMonad ~ m) => WriterT [AnyStatementWithResult     result] m a

doA :: Program result (result Int)
doA = do
  r <- lift statementAResult
  tell [AnyStatementWithResult $ StatementWithResult (StatementA, r)]
  return r

doB :: result Int -> Program result ()
doB arg = do
  r <- lift $ literalResult ()
  tell [AnyStatementWithResult $ StatementWithResult (StatementB arg, r)]

prog :: Program result ()
prog = do
  x <- doA
  doB x

data PrettyPrintResult x = PrettyPrintResult Int
  deriving Show

instance ResultClass PrettyPrintResult where
  type ResultMonad = IO
  statementAResult = PrettyPrintResult <$> randomIO
  literalResult _ = PrettyPrintResult <$> randomIO

printProg :: Program PrettyPrintResult a -> IO ()
printProg p = do
  stmts <- execWriterT p
  forM_ stmts $ \(AnyStatementWithResult (StatementWithResult (stmt, r))) -> do
    putStrLn $ "Statement: " ++ case stmt of
      StatementA -> "A"
      StatementB arg -> "B with arg " ++ show arg
    putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ show r

test :: IO ()
test = printProg prog
```

The problem itself lies in the `printProg` function that is expected to pretty-print an eDSL chunk. I wanted it to be able to work for all programs independent of their return type. But GHC complains:

```
untouchable.hs: line 52, column 18:
  Couldn't match type `a0' with `()'
    `a0' is untouchable
      inside the constraints (ResultClass PrettyPrintResult,
                              ResultMonad ~ m)
      bound by a type expected by the context:
                 (ResultClass PrettyPrintResult, ResultMonad ~ m) =>
                 WriterT [AnyStatementWithResult PrettyPrintResult] m a0
      at untouchable.hs:52:8-21
  Expected type: WriterT
                   [AnyStatementWithResult PrettyPrintResult] m a0
    Actual type: WriterT
                   [AnyStatementWithResult PrettyPrintResult] m ()
  In the first argument of `printProg', namely `prog'
  In the expression: printProg prog
```

If I replace the signature of `printProg` with `Program PrettyPrintResult () -> IO ()` everything builds and even works as expected.

So the question is why GHC fails to match a type variable, which is actually ignored by code? How could I rewrite `printProg` (or maybe other parts of code) that it would accept all the programs regardless of their result type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with the constraint in the type synonym for `Program`. Replace the type signature of `printProg` with the *real* type:

```
printProg :: WriterT [AnyStatementWithResult PrettyPrintResult] IO a -> IO ()
```

and it will compile. The constraint `m ~ ResultMonad` must be decided (is the given `m` a `ResultMonad` for the given `result`?), but the `m` is existential and no other information exists to help decide this. Why the error talks about `a` being untouchable, I have no idea. If you want good type errors, don't put constraints in type synonyms! The following change also fixes your problem:

```
type Program result a = 
  (ResultClass result) => WriterT [AnyStatementWithResult result] ResultMonad a
```

And finally, these problems are symptoms of a bigger problem. Note the following:

```
*Untouchable> :t lift statementAResult
lift statementAResult
  :: (ResultClass e, MonadTrans t) => t IO (e Int)
```

The `ResultMonad` immediately becomes `IO`! This is certainly wrong. The reason this happens is `lift` has a `Monad` constraint, and there is no way to get `Monad ResultMonad` - since `ResultMonad` depends on the type `result`, but `ResultMonad` does not have `result` in it anywhere. Essentially, your `result` and `ResultMonad` types have become completely unrelated.

The easy fix is to use a functional dependency instead of a type family:

```
class Monad m => ResultClass e m | e -> m where
  statementAResult :: m (e Int)
  literalResult    :: a -> m (e a)
```

You don't need the `Monad m` constraint but presumably your result monad must always be a monad. Then, write your `Program` type simply without any constraints:

```
type Program result m a = WriterT [AnyStatementWithResult result] m a
```

and put all constraints in the type of functions where they appear:

```
doA :: ResultClass result m => Program result m (result Int)

doB :: ResultClass result m => result Int -> Program result m ()

prog :: ResultClass result m => Program result m ()

-- etc ...
```

Not that now using `lift` no longer "forgets" your result monad type:

```
*Untouchable> :t lift statementAResult
lift statementAResult
  :: (ResultClass e m, MonadTrans t) => t m (e Int)
```

Comment: Ooooh, wow! I'm very grateful for helping me getting this all consistent, all your points are valid and very helpful. Wish I could upvote more times because your answer totally deserves it!